# Bind DNS server not responding to any requests

Tags: bind

I'm running bind on a CentOS 6.7 VPS, but I can't manage to make it respond to requests. I'm not sure, but I'm kinda suspecting some conflicts between m and loopback interfaces. Here is my ifconfig:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:47950 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:47950 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:5117063 (4.8 MiB)  TX bytes:5117063 (4.8 MiB)

venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  P-t-P:127.0.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: MY:EXT:IP:V6::IP/56 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:326740 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:136115 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:260931596 (248.8 MiB)  TX bytes:25033964 (23.8 MiB)

venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:MY.EXT.ERN.IP  P-t-P:MY.EXT.ERN.IP  Bcast:AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA  Mask:255.255.224.0
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Here is my `/etc/named.conf` (I highly doubt the issue comes from incuded conf files:

```
options {
        directory "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        forwarders {
        # these are the DNS servers from the VPS provider (look in /etc/resolv.conf if yours are different)
                MY.PROV.DNS.IP;
                8.8.8.8;
                8.8.4.4;
        };

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on { any; };
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
        allow-query { any; };
        allow-recursion { any; };
        allow-transfer { MY.PROV.DNS.IP;};
        recursion yes;
        dnssec-enable no;
        dnssec-validation no;

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};

#include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";

include "/etc/named.zones.override.fr";

logging {
        channel default_log {
                file "data/named.run" versions 5 size 30m;
                severity debug;
                print-time yes;
                print-severity yes;
                print-category yes;
        };

        category default { default_log; };
        category queries { default_log; };
};
```

I checked the conf with `named-checkconf -z`, it looks good. Here is a netstat:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      25         54195107   13451/named
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      25         54195112   13451/named
tcp        0      0 ::1:53                      :::*                        LISTEN      25         54195109   13451/named
tcp        0      0 ::1:953                     :::*                        LISTEN      25         54195113   13451/named
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53                0.0.0.0:*                               25         54195106   13451/named
udp        0      0 ::1:53                      :::*                                    25         54195108   13451/named
```

Now here are my tests results:

```
nslookup google.com 127.0.0.1
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
nslookup google.com MY.EXT.ERN.IP
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you nslookup Google.com 8.8.8.8 ?

Comment: I couldn't do anything at this time. I tried to reboot the VPS at some point and it started working... I really don't know what happened with his VPS. Thanks anyway guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First ports of call:

- Check /var/log/daemon.log
- Check the bind log
- Consider posting relevant loglines here
- Consider using dig instead of nslookup eg `dig google.com @127.0.0.1`